# How to resolve AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response in django and ajax

Tags: ajax, django

While I am calling Django url in ajax, getting below error

> AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response.

This is my code:

```
function download(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/mdm/exam_app/get_assessment_count/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
        },
        type:'GET',
        success: function (data) {
          alert("inside the success method");
    },
        error: function(){
          console.log("error");
          }        
      });
}
```

Comment: the error you're mentioning is a python error, so it happens in your django code. Why are you showing us your javascript code? show us the full error and the lines of code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you're using a function based view, then this issue usually means you forgot to add the [@api_view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) and the [@renderer_classes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers) decorator to your view.

Example:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def get_assessment_count(request):
    [...]
    data = {'count': queryset.count()}
    return Response(data, template_name='assessments.html')
```

Answer (score 19):

If anyone has this issue with *Django Rest Framework*  while using **Response** in a function based view, don't forget to use **@APIView** instead of **View** decorator.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer by @DavidLam it could also be that an error was thrown in your view/handler4xx/handler5xx and you've not caught it appropriately.

Comment: This helped me, it was an exception that I didn't handle correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to overriding the dispatch method of a view or ViewSet.  If you override that method and return without running the base/super version of the function, the renderer wont be setup on the response.

This is the line that sets the renderer on the response, in the source for APIView:

```
self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that using a predefined Response type instead of the general Response class fixed it.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_assessment_count(request):
    [...]
    data = {'count': queryset.count()}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing web API you must use API decorator to handle request and generate responses, so you should use `@api_view(['GET','POST'])` before functions.