# In Django, how do I render JSON given an OrderedDict?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, dictionary, serialization

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I'm having trouble returning JSON from one of my views.  I have this view code ...

```
def get_hints(request):
    article_id = request.GET.get('article_id', None)
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    s = ArticlesService()
    objects = s.get_hints(article)
    data = ArticleSerializer(objects, many=True).data
    print("data: ", data)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

The service method referenced returns the following data ...

```
def get_hints(self, article):
    ...
    sorted_articles_map = OrderedDict(sorted(rank_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
    return list(sorted_articles_map.keys())
```

The data returned from the serializer looks like this, definitely not json ...

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 10777935), ('created_on_ms', 1577985486000.0), ('label', 'World'), ('title', "Outrage and Disgust After 'Serial Killer' ...,
```

How do I render proper JSON?

**Edit:** Adding Article serializer ...

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'created_on_ms', 'label', 'title', 'mobile_path', 'path', 'url', 'is_media', 'checked_for_dup', 'original_path', 'is_spiked']
```

Comment: I'm confused where you expect your data to become serialized. What does `ArticleSerializer` do? None of the code you have posted seems to relate to JSON serialization. Have your tried simply writing `json.dumps(data)`?

Comment: You should show a simple example of the data your trying to serialize. Its hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: @Brian, I edited my question to include the Article serializer.  If I do the json.dumps as you suggest, I get the error, "TypeError: Object of type Article is not JSON serializable"

Comment: your `ArticleSerializer` expects a list of articles (`Article` instances) as input. It doesn't look like `objects` is actually a list of articles since it's the output of `get_hints` which is a list of keys (?). So what you're doing doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten, the service method returns a list of keys from an OrderedDict in which the keys are Article objects.  My question is how do I turn that list of keys into valid JSON?

Comment: It doesn't look like that's what it's doing, please print `objects`

Comment: `serializer.data` is a Python object. You need to serialize that to json somehow. If you go through the [rest framework tutorial part 1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) two options are to use `JSONRenderer` or `JSONResponse`. If you carry on to the [second part or the tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/), you'll see that a common approach is to use `return Response(data)`, then rest framework will decide how to serialize the data based on the `Accept` header.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, thanks for this info although I get an "AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response" error on my "return Response(data)" line.  Sure I'm missing something really obvious, just not sure what that is.

Comment: The tutorial suggests the view needs the `@api_view` decorator. If you search the error message, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416471/how-to-resolve-assertionerror-accepted-renderer-not-set-on-response-in-django) suggests you need the `@renderer_classes` decorator but I’m not sure that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Use the [**`@api_view()`**--(drf doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator of DRF along with [**`Response`**--(drf doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#response-objects) class

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_hints(request):
    article_id = request.GET.get('article_id', None)
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    s = ArticlesService()
    objects = s.get_hints(article)
    data = ArticleSerializer(objects, many=True).data
    return Response(data)
```

### Option 2

You will get similar response by using [**`JsonResponse`**--(django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse


def get_hints(request):
    article_id = request.GET.get('article_id', None)
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    s = ArticlesService()
    objects = s.get_hints(article)
    data = ArticleSerializer(objects, many=True).data
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Option one gives a "AssertionError: @api_view missing list of allowed HTTP methods" error but option 2 appears to be working.  Going to run a few more tests but I'm thinking option 2 is a winner.