# Django Rest Framework Api View GET

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my codes, I have a model Tweet, and in tweet_list_view, I want to show the list of tweets as API view.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def tweet_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Tweet.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    serializer = TweetSerializer(data=qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is what I got as a result.

```
AssertionError at /tweets/
When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.
```

So I called the .is_valid method like following:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def tweet_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Tweet.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    serializer = TweetSerializer(data=qs, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response({}, status=400)
```

Then I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /tweets/
rest_framework/api.html
```

At serializers.py
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Tweet
fields = ['content', 'date_posted', 'likes']

models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

It's looking for a template, but it's supposed to use the default Django template. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: did add `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use **`data`** argument to serialize model objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

forgot the @ in front of the api_view. Added it. Also added the renderer_class (jsonrenderer) to make sure avoiding the error.

---

You need to use the data attribute of the serializer only when you have a post, put or patch view. In your case just try it without the data attribute and it should be fine

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer]) 
def tweet_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    qs = Tweet.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted') 
    serializer = TweetSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here you can see it in the tutorial example of the official [django rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)

Comment: I used your code, but I got `AssertionError at /tweets/.accepted_renderer not set on Response`

Comment: can you please add your model and your serializer?

Comment: I don't think its related to your model or serializer, instead you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416471/how-to-resolve-assertionerror-accepted-renderer-not-set-on-response-in-django)

Comment: can you try to add the renderer_class for your function-based view. Here is a reference where this problem is solved by adding the renderer_class: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417280/13347371](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417280/13347371)

Comment: well that was at the same time :D I dont use function-based views very often, thats why I didnt notice that at first.

Comment: Updated my answer.