# Django url dispatch error - AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: django

I am dispatching based on the path to my methods in the class.
The problem arises when I have to pass it to a post method.
Else I can wrap it over a Request using the process_request method.

How do I pass the correct request to the methods
which is not HttpRequest but the DRF 3 Request I suppose.

```
class AddInvoice(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(request, HttpRequest):
            return Request(request,parsers=[MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser, DjangoMultiPartParser])
        return request

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser, DjangoMultiPartParser, FileUploadParser)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = None
        #request = AddInvoice.process_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            if request.path.rstrip('/') == '/invoice/digitize':
                response = self.digitize(request,*args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            if request.path.startswith('/invoice/isdigitized/'):
                response = self.isdigitized(request, *args,
                                             **kwargs)
            elif request.path.startswith('/invoice/get/'):
                response = self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            if request.path.rstrip('/') == '/invoice':
                response = self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not response:
            response = Response(status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        if not getattr(request, 'accepted_renderer', None):
            neg = self.perform_content_negotiation(request, force=True)
            request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg
        response.accepted_renderer = request.accepted_renderer
        response.accepted_media_type = request.accepted_media_type
        response.renderer_context = self.get_renderer_context()
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some alternate way to bypass the issue creating a class of APIView as an object and using it `add_invoice = AddInvoice()` and get an alternate solution.
Django hasn't been very kind there is no other alternative to convert this to DRF 3 Request.

```
@staticmethod
@api_view(["GET", 'PUT', "POST"])
def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = None
    add_invoice = AddInvoice()
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        if request.path.rstrip('/') == '/invoice/digitize':
            response = add_invoice.digitize(request, *args, **kwargs)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if request.path.startswith('/invoice/isdigitized/'):
            response = add_invoice.isdigitized(request, *args,
                                              **kwargs)
        elif request.path.startswith('/invoice/get/'):
            response = add_invoice.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if request.path.rstrip('/') == '/invoice':
            response = add_invoice.post(request)

    if not response:
        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    if not getattr(request, 'accepted_renderer', None):
        neg = add_invoice.perform_content_negotiation(request, force=True)
        request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg
    response.accepted_renderer = request.accepted_renderer
    response.accepted_media_type = request.accepted_media_type
    response.renderer_context = add_invoice.get_renderer_context()
    return response
```